# Gwt-приложения под Internet Explorer 9 (beta)

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer

Привет! Пробовали ли вы запускать GWT-приложения на IE9 Beta? В сети пишут, что Gwt поддерживает IE9 только начиная с версии 2.3. Если так, то стоит ли сейчас переходить на эту версию (Gwt 2.3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стоит. Ранние версии не поддерживают IE9. Можете проверить на [www.seemap.ru](http://www.seemap.ru), он написан на gwt (не на последней версии)